# Best way to display wanted data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a college student and still learning. Here is my project;
When a user logins in, they can add Products to a basket. They then proceed to the address/payment where they enter address and card details. What I need to make is a "View Orders" where a user can view previous made orders, what is the best recommended way of doing this? Not asking for all ways, just what you think is the most effective for displaying this information.
The View Orders needs to display there order details, address, name etc and beneath it the products in the order.
Please view my classes below for more information;

Order

```
 public partial class Order
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Remote("CheckUserName", "Account")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Your name is too long")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required.")]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Last name is too long.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required.")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Email doesn't look like a valid email address.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Email")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm your email address")]
        public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }


        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }


        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public bool HasBeenShipped { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }

        public CardDetails cardDetails { get; set; }
        //public List<CardDetails> cardDetails { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

OrderDetail class

```
 public class OrderDetail
    {
        public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

Product Class

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Colour { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductImg { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE**
Controller;

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
        var viewModel = (from o in new TshirtStoreDB().Orders
                    select new OrderArchiveViewModel
                    {
                        Address = o.Address,
                        City = o.City,
                        OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                        PostalCode = o.PostalCode,
                         Details = (from d in o.OrderDetails
                                    select new OrderDetailArchive
                                    {
                                        Description = d.Product.Description,
                                        Quantity = d.Quantity,
                                        Title = d.Product.Title,
                                        UnitPrice = d.UnitPrice
                                    }).ToList()
                    }).ToList() ;

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

*ERROR FIXED*

```
public class TshirtStoreDB : DbContext
{

    public TshirtStoreDB() : base("name=TshirtStoreDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

}
```

My View;

```
@model T_shirt_Company_v3.ViewModels.OrderArchiveViewModel

<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var m in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@m.OrderDate</td>
                <td>@m.Address</td>
                <td>@m.City</td>
                <td>@m.PostalCode</td>
                <td><button class="btnDetails">Details</button></td>
            </tr>
            foreach (var d in m.Details)
                {
                <tr style="display: none;">
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@d.Title</td>
                                    <td>@d.Description</td>
                                    <td>@d.Quantity</td>
                                    <td>@d.UnitPrice</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Error:

> T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.OrderArchiveViewModel: : EntityType
>   'OrderArchiveViewModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.
>
> T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.OrderDetailArchive: : EntityType
>   'OrderDetailArchive' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.
>
> OrderArchiveViewModels: EntityType: EntitySet 'OrderArchiveViewModels'
>   is based on type 'OrderArchiveViewModel' that has no keys defined.
>
> OrderDetailArchives: EntityType: EntitySet 'OrderDetailArchives' is
>   based on type 'OrderDetailArchive' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Are you asking how to go about persisting the data to a database and how to retrieve the past orders from the database? Are you using Entity Framework Code First? It looks like you are per the data annotations but more info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create new class/model which will has all info which you need. For example

```
public class OrderArchive
{
   public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
   public string PostalCode { get; set; }
   public List<OrderDetailArchive> Details { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetailArchive
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

It's just example how it can looks, use columns which you need.
Then you have to get from database you data and put in into your object. Using this model you can get this by this code

```
var list = (from o in new dbContext().Order
           select new OrderArchive
           {
                Address = o.Address,
                City = o.City,
                OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                PostalCode = o.PostalCode
                Details = (from d in o.OrderDetails
                          select new OrderDetailArchive
                          {
                              Description = d.Product.Description,
                              Quantity = d.Quantity,
                              Title = d.Product.Title,
                              UnitPrice = d.UnitPrice
                          }).ToList()
           }).ToList();
```

Create new view `OrderArchive` and display it into table.

```
@model OrderArchive

<table>
   <tbody>
   @foreach(var m in Model)
   {
      <tr>
         <td>@m.OrderDate</td>
         <td>@m.Address</td>
         <td>@m.City</td>
         <td>@m.PostalCode</td>
         <td><button class="btnDetails">Details</button></td>
      </tr>
      foreach(var d in m.Details
      {
         <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>
               <table>
                  <tbody>    
                     <tr>
                        <td>@d.Title</td>
                        <td>@d.Description</td>
                        <td>@d.Quantity</td>
                        <td>@d.UnitPrice</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      }
   }
   <tbody>
</table>
```

Now you need some javascript which will show order details when you click on button *Details* will display row with subtable with details.

```
$('.btnDetails').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().next().css('display', '');
});
```

Simple example:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/0keogrx2/

Comment: That's a great example and explanation, could I trouble you further @Sousuke? How would I fill the object from he database with the controller?

Comment: slight problem, adjusted my main question with it @Sousuke

Comment: sorry, I make mistake, it should be `new TshirtStoreDB().Orders` (I've update answer. And you should return your Action like this `return View(viewModel);`

Comment: That has worked perfectly! Don't know how I didnt spot it myself haha. New error popped up in the view though, any idea whats causing that? Edited question @Sousuke if you get a moment

Comment: You set your model as object but you have a list, so `@model List<T_shirt_Company_v3.ViewModels.OrderArchiveViewModel>`

Comment: Bugger, now it keeps telling me that OrderArchiveViewModel has no keys defined?! @Sousuke edited question with full error

Comment: Have you checked in debugger if your model has any value?

Comment: Problem is different, why application think your view model is entity framework object? Have you added it into your context, add some attribute to classes?

Comment: might need to add into context, one moment and ill try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109143/discussion-between-sousuke-and-andre-queen).

Comment: What do you mean @Sousuke ? I haven't removed anything
Oooh nevermind, I see the tick, I must have accidentally clicked again, sorry haha

Answer (score 1):

You can add `View Orders` link in the user profile section. Simple way is to create a `table` with Order Headers. If the user wants to drill down further then you can display Order Details. A suggestion would be to check out how ebay and amazon provide similar functionality.

Comment: I have in the Index a link to M Account, this is where the user will be able to view there orders. What do you mean create a table with Order headers? How would I go about doing that

Comment: What i am suggesting is you create a view where you will display hystorical orders. Now its easier to display this data in a table, so in that view you must place a table. Also it would make sense to only display the summury of the orders in that table, and let the user decide if he/she wants to drill down and see the details.

Comment: Does my answer make sense? Which part does not make sense?

Comment: You're answer makes great sense, next answer just goes into more how to do it, thank you very much!